# Does google protobuf work in unity for ios and android?

Tags: unity-game-engine, protocol-buffers

I want to create a game for ios and android. The game will send and get msg from server. I want to use google protobuf, does it work in unity?

Comment: Yes. I did not implement it but used other developers code in a project for both platforms

Comment: It does work in Unity. [This](http://purdyjotut.blogspot.com/2013/10/using-protobuf-in-unity3d.html) should get you started.

Comment: Thanks. @Programmer.  That's protobuf-net. Does you know google protobuf 3.1.0 or over work in unity, and to build ios and android game?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution [protobuf_for_unity](https://github.com/GongFaxin/protobuf_for_unity)